# Horizontal recyclerview inside another horizontal recyclerview doesnt show sometimes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I have list of events inside recyclerview and each event has tags which are again recyclerview inside each event.
The problem is sometimes it doesnt show on a device and when app is restarted it started to show again.
Data comes rightly and thats why these two tags items are showing and with the right width.issue is with height here

Anyone had similar issue and found the solution?Please help
[image]

code of event item

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="@dimen/home_card_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/upperLayout"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/home_card_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/eventCover"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
                <View
                    android:background="@color/background_layer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/shopMainBcg"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="140dp">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="0.0"
                            android:id="@+id/tv_rating"
                            style="@style/ratingStyle"
                            android:visibility="invisible"
                            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/ll_likeBtnCont"/>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/ll_likeBtnCont"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/favouriteVGSize"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/favouriteVGSize"
                            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:padding="12dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_heart_bg100dp_white">
                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                app:tint="@color/expandable_list_parent_color"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_heart"
                                android:id="@+id/img_heart" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/eventStartDateCardView"
                            style="@style/eventCardDateVGStye"
                            android:visibility="visible"
                            android:layout_above="@id/textLayout">
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/eventStartDate"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:text="@string/dummy_date"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="15sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:background="@drawable/shop_open_btn"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:padding="8dp"
                                android:visibility="visible">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/eventStartDay"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:text="@string/dummy_day"
                                    android:textColor="@color/eventBooking"
                                    android:textSize="13sp"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/eventStartYear"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:text="@string/dummy_day"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                                    android:textSize="13sp"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/textLayout"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            style="@style/postTitleStyleHomeVG">
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/eventName"
                                android:text="@string/dummy_listing_name"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                style="@style/postTitleStyleHome"/>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/eventCategories"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_below="@id/shopMainBcg"
                        android:layout_marginTop="-22dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/event_card_tags_margin_start"
                        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>

                </RelativeLayout>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_below="@id/upperLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/imageLayout"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/hostedByLayout"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/eventVendorProfile"
                    style="@style/mapEventLogoSizeStyle"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>
                <ImageView
                    style="@style/explorePostsExtrasIconStyle1"
                    android:src="@drawable/address_small_icon" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/eventVendorName"
                    android:text="@string/hosted_by"
                    style="@style/explorePostsExtrasTextStyle1" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please add the code for more clarity.

Comment: Code added @AbdullahJaved